# What is the vim equivalent of emacs' ctrl-k?

Tags: vim

How can I delete from the current cursor position to the end of line in vim's insert mode?

I know you can do this with `D` in command mode, and I know you can delete from the cursor position to the *beginning* of the line in insert mode with ctrl-u, so I'm guessing this should be possible.

Comment: Well, yes, it's `D`. What is the question?

Comment: I want D, but in insert mode.

Comment: I think that the best solution for it would be "going back to NORMAL" mode by `ESC` or `C-O` if you really want to stay in INSERT. Don't be afraid to leave INSERT mode. You do only **Insert** there, most time you should stay in NORMAL.  Otherwise INSERT should be called NORMAL. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're in insert mode and you want to execute a single normal mode command, you can press:

<kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd>

After the normal mode command has executed, you'll be returned to insert mode. So, you can use <kbd>D</kbd> that way:

<kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: And that could be reduced to a single key combination with `inoremap <C-k> <C-o>D` (I think)

Comment: As @Kent says, Ctrl+k is useful for diagraphs, so some other mapping might be a better idea.

Comment: And the last time you used digraphs was ... when?

Comment: I actually use them quite regularly, but that's up to the OP I guess!

Comment: Exactly, it's one of those things you either use all the time, or barely even know exists.

Comment: @ams I have HHKB Pro2, and I type `üäß...` with it. well if you asked me when was the last time? I say right now. since I post answer/comment here in vim.  Anyway, your answer is good. I voted it up! :-)

Comment: I am not even surprised anymore when someone wonders if anyone at all uses something in Vim I use all the time.

Comment: I meant, voted this answer... I thought it was from @ams .. sorry.

Comment: There is a big difference: when you repeatedly press Ctrl+K, it appends the deleted content to the kill-ring (= the default register in vim terminology).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method for this in VIM, but you can use this map to use Ctrl+k in VIM as you would in Emacs:

```
inoremap <C-k> <Del>
```

However, if you want to you the built in digraph functionality of VIM for writing special characters, you should use a different keybinding like .

Comment: I won't have this mapping, it disabled default `digraphs`

Comment: Then just use a different mapping. The questioner asked for CTRL+k, but you could use any other mapping like CTRL+d.

Comment: ok... but how do you make `<del>` delete the stuff between current pos and the EOF? btw, `ctrl-d` in insert mode is even more useful than `ctrl-k` it plays with indentations.

Comment: @Kent This was not the question. The question is 'from the current cursor position to the end of line'. You could achieve deletion to the end of line in VIMs command mode by hitting DG.

Comment: +1 for this answer -- good to know it's not really possible so I don't keep looking, and the remap suggestion is helpful.

Comment: @Munen does `<Del>` do  delete `from the current cursor position to the end of line`? Or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in equivalent (to the best of my knowledge).

The simplest way from insert mode is to use [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O) [<kbd>D</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#D).

If you'd like to map this to something a little easier to remember, you may wish to create an [insert-mode mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:inoremap), which will allow you to [use the normal-mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O) [<kbd>D</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#D) command to delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line:

```
:inoremap <Leader>k <C-O>D
```

Assuming [`<Leader>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader) is the default `\`, you would type <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> in insert mode invoke the mapping.

Insert-mode mappings are not without their drawbacks, as Kent points out in the comments but do have their uses.

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-K) is used for entering [digraphs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraphs) in Vim. I'd suggest that you don't try to re-map this, although it is possible using the technique above.

Comment: @downvoter: Can you please point out how I can improve my answer?

Comment: I don't downvote any answers on SO, but I guess there are some problems in your answer. 1, with `C-O`, you dont need the `ESC` in mapping. With that `ESC`, you go back to NORMAL.  2, I am always careful for INSERT mapping, sometime it is not easy to find a suitable insertmode mapping. E.g. your `<Leader>k` if `Leader` was `\`, someone want to type/edit a windows path:`c:\\some\path\kill bill\...` I think you see the problem.  also , if your Leader was `,(comma)`,  `,k` could be also used very often in Insert.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks. No idea why I added `<Esc>`. That's been removed. Your concerns regarding the drawbacks of insert-mode mappings are definitely valid!

Answer (score 0):

If you also want bind `<C-k>` to kill-line in command-line mode, you can use the `getcmdline()` and `getcmdpos()` functions:

```
cnoremap <C-k> <C-\>e(" ".getcmdline())[:getcmdpos()-1][1:]<CR>
```